# Applying numfmt on a specific column in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, tcsh

I'm writing a script in `tcsh` (yes... I know but I have to) to analyze all users disk usage in a specific directory.

In the end, I want to produce a report in the next format:

```
user1 1.6GB
user2 1.1GB
..
user69 10MB
```

First I'm running

```
find . -printf "%u  %s\n" | awk '{user[$1]+=$2}; END{ for( i in user) print i " " user[i]}' > example.tmp
```

and then I managed to convert the 2nd column to human-readable size by:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' example.tmp | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7
```

yet I was not able to merge it back in place of the previous column.
Is there a way to inject the `numfmt` command directly into the `awk` summation?

I'm a little weak with 'awk' commands, so pardon my bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to avoid doing that by using the `--field` option of `numfmt` to limit the formating to only the second field directly, i.e.

```
find . -printf "%u  %s\n" | 
  awk '{user[$1]+=$2}; END{ for(i in user) print i, user[i]}' | 
  numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7
```

If you really need to apply `numfmt` on as specific value from within awk, then here's a variant that works for simple cases and does not require `getline var`:

```
find . -printf "%u  %s\n" | 
  awk '
    {user[$1]+=$2}
    END {
      cmd = "numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7"; 
      for(i in user){ printf "%s ", i; print user[i] | cmd; close(cmd) } 
    }
  '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by calling the `numfmt` command from within `awk`, such as:

```
awk '{cmd=sprintf("numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 %d",$2); cmd | getline converted; close(cmd); print $1,converted}' example.tmp
```

That way, you could also directly implement it in your first `awk` call:

```
find . -printf "%u  %s\n" | awk '{user[$1]+=$2};
  END{
     for(i in user) {
        cmd=sprintf("numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B %d",user[i]);
        cmd | getline converted;
        close(cmd);
        printf("%s % 7s\n",i,converted)
     }
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and worked fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess
from os import *
users=[]
for i,j,k in os.walk('<directory>'):
    for m in  k:
        fil=str(i)+str(m)
        if os.path.isfile(fil):
            if os.stat(fil).st_uid not in users:
                users.append(os.stat(fil).st_uid)



for u in users:
    size=0
    for i,j,k in os.walk('<Directory>'):
        for z in k:
            fil=str(i)+str(z)
            if os.path.isfile(fil):
                if (os.stat(fil).st_uid == u):
                    size=os.stat(fil).st_size+size
    cmd1="getent passwd {0}".format(u)
    ou1=subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0].strip().split(':')[0]
    print size,ou1
~                                                                                                                                             
~
```